# Слайдер для увеличения(уменьшения) скорости игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я сделал 3-х позиционный слайдер в настройках игры и хочу чтобы он менял скорость персонажа в зависимости от положения слайдера. Как это реализовать? Примерный код на данный момент такой.

```
public class GameSettings : MonoBehaviour {

    public Slider mainSlider;

    private void start () {
        mainSlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {ValueChangeCheck(); });
}

    public void ValueChangeCheck()
    {
       Debug.Log(mainSlider.value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

У слайдера есть функция OnValueChanged,зачем усложнять?
Я бы сделал так:

```
[SerializeField]
Slider slider
[SerializeField]
Player player;



 public void OnValueChange()
{
  player.speed = slider.value;
}
```

player - скрипт игрока.
player.speed - глобальная переменная которая используется при движении.Например: "AddForce".

Ps:Не забудь слайдеру добавить слайдеру что он должен использовать эту фун-цию при изменении значения.
[image: Вот]

Comment: попробуем, спасибо)